# Откуда буква Д в слове "швед"?

Tags: словообразование

Названия жителей страны образуются по-разному (достаточно вспомнить: русский, немец, англичанин, индиец), но все-таки в них есть какая-то логика. Но, честно говоря, не могу найти логики в образовании слова "швед". Откуда тут взялась буква Д, когда страна называется Швеция? По идее, должно быть "швец".
Или же букву Д употребляют, чтобы название национальности не совпадало с обозначением профессии портного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово «швед» заимствовано через нем. Schwede , а «Швеция»  - книжное заимств. из ср.-лат., нов.-лат. Suecia.

Изначально на Руси шведов называли свеями.

Свеи (швед. svear, sviar) — древнегерманское племя, жившее на территории нынешней Швеции. Термин также использовался как собирательное название населения древней Швеции.